# jQuery data element weird behavior

Tags: jquery

I have a set of elements with a data attribute called mod, as shown below:

```
<div data-mod="2">Close</div>
<div data-mod="0">Ban</div>
```

And a jQuery function to check if one of the divs has been clicked, followed by an alert confirmation to handle the action or not.

```
$("body").on("click", "div[data-mod]", function() {
    var btn = $(this);
    if (btn.hasClass("inactive")) {
        return false;
    } else {
        var confirm = alert.Confirm("Are you sure?");
        $("body").on("click", "[data-alert=0]", function() {
            alert.Close($(this).parents("#alert"));
            return false;
        });
        $("body").on("click", "[data-alert=1]", function() {
            console.info(btn);
            btn.addClass("inactive");
        });
    }
});
```

The issue is if you cancel the alert and then click the next div and confirm the action, both clicked divs will get the "inactive" class, as var btn is now the two clicked divs. If for instance, there are three divs and only two clicked, the third div remains with its original class.

Is there any way to get var btn to store only the value of the last clicked div rather than both values?

Thanks in advance,

Mateus

**UPDATE**

```
$("body").on("click", "div[data-mod]", function() {
    var btn = $(this);
    if (btn.hasClass("inactive")) {
        return false;
    } else {
        alert.Check("Tem certeza?");
        $("body").on("click", "[data-alert=0]", function() {
            alert.Close($(this).parents("#alert"));
            return false;
        });
        $("body").on("click", "[data-alert=1]", function() {
            console.info(btn);
            btn.addClass("inactive");
        });
    }
});
```

The alert variable is:

```
var alert = {
  Check: function() {
    var content = $("#contentalerts");
    $.get("/../static/alertconfirm.tpl", function(alert) {
      content.append(alert);
      content.find("#alert").last().draggable();
    });
    content.on("click", ".close", function() {
      alert.Close($(this).parents("#alert"));
    });
    $(window).on("keyup", function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 27) alert.Close($("#alert").last());
    });
  },
  Close: function(content) {
    content.remove();
  } 
};
```

Comment: What is `alert.Confirm`?

Comment: @Rajesh snippet added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `confirm` as your variable name, that's a reserved word.

Try to rename it then test it whether resolve your weird problem or not.

Please refer to [Windows Reserved Words](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are using a custom confirm or alert box in your code. Like @Hinx said, `confirm` is a reserved word. So better avoid it for use as variables!

Anyway, here's a small rearrangement of your code so as to give you an idea:

```
var btn;

$("body").on("click", "div[data-mod]", function() {
    btn = $(this);
    if (btn.hasClass("inactive")) {
        return false;
    } else {

        // show your custom confirm box here
        $('#my_custom_confirm_box').show();

    }
});

$("body").on("click", "[data-alert=0]", function() {
    $('#my_custom_confirm_box').hide();

    return false;
});
$("body").on("click", "[data-alert=1]", function() {    
    $(btn).addClass("inactive");

    $('#my_custom_confirm_box').hide();

    return false;
});
```